# How to use parallelism in Julia to speed up combinatorial checking?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, julia, combinations

Given a bunch of nested for loops, I wish to find the best combination of values according to some metric, and I want to keep track of the best combination and the best result.

I gave an example (below) of how a very basic version of what I want would look like sequentially. However, I realize that this problem can be easily parallelized, especially if I can generate all combinations and then run the `check` function for each combination at the same time.

In my specific use case, the `check` function takes the majority of the time, so it is a clear bottleneck in my algorithm. My intuition is that if I were to create an array of tasks, I could run these tasks all at once and achieve a considerable speedup.

Given my requirements, how would I implement this in Julia? In Java, I know I could use something like `ForkJoinPool` and add a slew of tasks that way, but I am unsure of the Julia equivalent.

```
function check(parameters)
    return value(parameters)
end

bestCheck = 0 
bestParameters = []
for a in 1:30
   for b in 1:50
       for c in 1:90
           temp = check(a,b,c)
           if temp > bestCheck
               bestCheck = temp
               bestParameters = [a b c]
           end
        end
    end
end

println(bestCheck)
println(bestParameters)
```

Comment: does `check` vary relatively slowly with the parameters? If so, using optimization techniques will be way better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
using Distributed
addprocs(16) # whatever CPU / vCPU you have
@everywhere function check(a,b, c)
    a^2 - 2b - 45c + c^2
end

best = @distributed max for (a,b,c) in vec(collect(Iterators.product(1:30, 1:50, 1:90)))
    (check(a,b,c), a,b,c)
end
```

```
julia> best
(4948, 30, 1, 90)
```

As you can see in Julia this kind of code i short.
`Distributed` is an equivalent of `multiprocessing` in Python but much more powerful. `@everywhere` defines function in all nodes around the cluster. `@distributed` in this scenario uses an aggregator function which is max. We distribute computing of a Cartesian Product of all parameters - in distributed scenario this is usually better than nested loops. Also note that the order of parameter matters when computation times depend on parameter values. The loop yields a tuple that goes to the `max` aggregator function.